# Grails: Accessing the request paramters without wiping them out

Tags: grails, web-applications

According to the document on command objects and data binding. Once you read the params object, that object can never be reused again.

From the documentation:

**Binding The Request Body To Command Objects**
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects

> Note that the body of the request is being parsed to make that work. Any attempt to read the body of the request after that will fail since the corresponding input stream will be empty. The controller action can either use a command object or it can parse the body of the request on its own (either directly, or by referring to something like request.JSON), but cannot do both.

I'm trying to view the parameters within a filter (which is hit before the controller is requested). Would logging the parameters to a log cause the controller to get a null param object? From the documentation that looks to be the case. However, how can I get access to the params without wiping them out in the filter?

Comment: You may be confusing the request body with request parameters.  The body is an `InputStream` so once it is read, you are at the end of the stream so it can't be read again.  Request parameters can be accessed repeatedly, as many times as it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once you read the params object, that object can never be reused
>   again.

That is not correct.  You can read request parameters over and over again.  What cannot be read over and over again is the body of the request.  The body and the request parameters are 2 different things.

Comment: Your question doesn't really indicate this but if you what you really want is to read the body of the request in a filter, you can do that and then do what you want with the results but then you won't be able to read the body again later. If you want to read the body in a filter and then later access some of that information, the filter could put that data in the params map, or store it in the session, or in a stateful bean etc... (you have lots of options), but it isn't clear if that is really what you are trying to do anyway.

Comment: So just to confirm, the params object off of a filter can be seen and reused without a negative impact to the controller?
I believe that you answered my question on the HTTP.get metaclass issue. I still need to post a ticket on that.

Comment: "So just to confirm, the params object off of a filter can be seen and reused without a negative impact to the controller?" - that is correct.  You can pull values out of `params` over and over again.

Comment: "I believe that you answered my question on the HTTP.get metaclass issue. I still need to post a ticket on that." - That doesn't ring a bell.  To what are you referring?